# Degree of normal closure of number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Let $K\subset E\subset F$ be a tower of number fields (i.e. finite extensions of $\mathbb Q$). Assume $E/K$ and $F/E$ are non-trivial normal extensions, and let $F^*/K$ be the normal closure of $F/K$.

What are the (optimal) bounds for $[F^*:K]$ in terms of $[F:E]$ and $[E:K]$?

Comment: From the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, it follows that $\mathrm{Gal}(F^*/K)$ is a subgroup of the wreath product $\mathrm{Gal}(F/E) \wr \mathrm{Gal}(E/K)$ and moreover this will be the generic situation, giving the optimal bound $[E:K] \cdot [F:E]^{[E:K]}$.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your very good answer. Two follow up questions: What happens with the bounds when we remove the assumption that E/K is Galois? What do you mean by generic?

Comment: If you go through the exercise of actually understanding my comment, the answers to your followup should also be clear.

Comment: Ok, I will try my best. Thanks.